# i want use placeholder to get data from user input kivy mysql

Tags: mysql, kivy

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="12123123412"
            database='newdb')
      
cur = conn.cursor()
    
xx_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["rgr"].text
ee_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["gfd"].text

qur = f"SELECT * FROM  (%s)  WHERE bedrooms = '(%s)' "

val = (xx_zz, ee_zz)

cur.execute(qur, val)
    
records = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I would really appreciate assistance as I cannot figure this out.

Comment: what results are you getting? is there an error message? Have you checked the connection parameters? Have you checked the values which are in `(xx_zz, ee_zz)` at execution?

Comment: thanks Kendle for your replay, the values which will define the table name and column name suppose to get it from the user           xx_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["rgr"].text
ee_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["gfd"].text

Comment: xx_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["rgr"].text
        ee_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["gfd"].text

        qur = f" SELECT * FROM {xx_zz} WHERE bedrooms = '{ee_zz}' "
 cur.execute(qur)                                                                             i am trying to do it since 5 days but i couldn't get it

Comment: i am getting this error                                                                                  1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE bedrooms = ' '' at line 1

Comment: Please can you print out the actual values of xx_zz and ee_zz at execution so that we know what the query is?

Comment: How do you control whether there is a table called xx_zz containg a column bedrooms in schema?

Comment: the values of xx_zz  will be lusail  which is a user choise from tables names                                                                         
the values of ee_zz  will be lusail which is a user choise from columns names

Comment: xx_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["rgr"].text  in this varible there is a drop down menu has limited choices of the tables names , so the user will chose only from the drop down menu

Comment: Yes I understand that. You can use the value directly with string concatenation if you are 100% sure that nobody can inject other values by any means. I am trying to help you avoid the possible risk.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that we use a function to create the query string using match-case. This will avoid any risk of SQL injection as we are not using the string provided by the front end.
You will need to modify and complete the option values and table names and decide whether there should be a default table name or no result if the option provided is not found.
Obviously this code has not been tested.

```
def makeQuery( option ):
    match option:
        case 'option1':
            return f"SELECT * FROM table_name_1 WHERE bedrooms = '(%s)' "
        case 'option2':
            return f"SELECT * FROM table_name_2 WHERE bedrooms = '(%s)' "
        case _:        
            return f"SELECT * FROM default_table_name WHERE bedrooms = '(%s)' "
            
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="12123123412"
database='newdb')
      
cur = conn.cursor()
    
xx_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["rgr"].text
ee_zz = self.screen.get_screen('end').ids["gfd"].text

qur = makeQuery(xx_zz )

val = ( ee_zz )

cur.execute(qur, val)
    
records = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: do you mean I should replace 'option1' by table name or as it is,  and table_name_1 to be replaced by the table name also etc     another thing with this code I am getting an invalid syntax  <option>

Comment: match option:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: thank you so much Kendle, you tried to assist but it seems to be complicated or i still need to read more about it to be able to understand these points, thanks again

Answer (score -1):

In textInput (field) you use `hint_text` to show a placeholder in a text field(input).